# ITMS-90561: Invalid Swift Support - The watchOS application has Swift libraries at both - Xcode 12

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect

I recently tried to submit an update to an app that I have been constantly updating, the last update was done using Xcode 11.  This time when I Distributed the App using Xcode 12, everything went smoothly without any errors but after a few minutes, I got the following email from Apple.

### Email

[image]

But I'm not really sure what do I need to do to make it work.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by changing `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` from Yes to **No**. for the Watch App.

[image]

Comment: Worked with complication extension!